# Django_filter - pass slug from views.py function to filters.py class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter

I have written a function that filters certain parameters. This function needs the slug, which I get from the url. Inside my views.py function I defined the slug as a variable. I want to pass this to the function in the filters.py.

views.py

```
def platform_list(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    f = PlatformFilter(request.GET, queryset=Platform.objects.filter(category=category))

    return render(request, 'core/platform-list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'filter': f
    })
```

filters.py

```
class PlatformFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    def nesseccary_functionalities(slug):
        # select nesseccary functionalities
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        categoryNesseccary = list(category.filter_functions.values('functionality'))
        filter_funcs = list(Functionality.objects.values_list('functionality', flat=True))

        for count, x in enumerate(categoryNesseccary):
            if x['functionality'] in filter_funcs:
                filter_funcs.remove(x['functionality'])
        return filter_funcs
        # return ['a','b']

    nesseccary = Functionality.objects.all().exclude(functionality__in=nesseccary_functionalities(<slugNeededHere>))
```

The nesseccary_functionalities returns an array of values I want to exclude(it works fine).
Is there a way to transfer the slug from the platform_list function in views.py to the  filters.py so I can **use the slug to run the nesseccary_functionalities function**?

Comment: Can you clarify, can't you just `import PlatformFilter` into `views.py` and use it there?

Comment: I imported PlattformFilter and set queryset to filter things. But I need the slug parameter in the PlattformFilter. Is there a way I can pass another parameter to PlattformFilter?